# How could turn two monitors connected in one PC acting like two different devices?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, multiple-monitors

I would like to use my two monitors which are connected to my PC to be acting like two different devices. How could I achieve this?

My requirements:

My second display is touchable pad which would customers use for informations, application use, interactive commercial view etc. Touchable pad extends primary desktop monitor.
OS is Windows 7.
I would like to achieve that customer and user of PC works simultaneously and that mouse pointer doesn't go in second monitor.
I would like to have some free program or write an app to do this. I can write an app in C# or Java. I just need some guides.

Comment: How about to create a [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or a [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/) and open that machine on your second screen?

Comment: Not an option because of enterpise enviroment and many licences for virtual machine and OS.

Comment: Then you should clarify every limitation in your question. Also what kind of devices you want to have, which operating system you are using, why you want to achieve that, and so on

Comment: I added to my original post.

Comment: To my knowledge this isn't possible. You can have 2 different things running on each screen, and you can prevent the mouse cursor from entering screen 2, but touch, kbd and mouse use the same [HID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_device) systems, so preventing any cross-interaction is likely to be hard. (Eg if you're pressing control when someone touches the screen, it'll be a Ctrl-Press event). Additionally, only one window can have focus at a time. Even if you had VMs, _one_ of them has to be focused. My advice... Buy a tiny PC/refurbed laptop to run the customer screen

Comment: It is possible. Microsoft has Multipointsever which turns one computer into many devices. I am searching for less heavy solution.

Comment: @Igor That's not the same thing at all. That is multiple concurrent user desktops served from one machine. Nowhere does it use one desktop for multiple users/purposes. In addition, desktop versions of windows are limited to a single user session at a given time so unless your staff/visitors are going to be running Windows Server, you're going to have licensing issues too

Answer (score 1):

I don't really have the exact answer to your question but I'll just offer some alternatives since I did some research on this as well. Hopefully the alternatives might be of your consideration.

[This SO question](https://superuser.com/questions/29432/using-windows-7-how-can-you-use-multiple-mice-to-get-multiple-cursors) might be of interest, since you get many mouse pointers, perhaps you could use that and look into setting up boundaries that disallow one pointer from moving to another.

**Modifying registry values, violates ToS**

As Basic has mentioned is not possible to have concurrent users running on a desktop install. At least legally. Research online shows it is relatively easy to modify the system registry to 'unlock' this. But clearly this violates the ToS of Microsoft and you probably cannot do it in an enterprise environment. People use it for home systems where they want to be able to keep a separate user just for the home media center and don't need a full server for that.

**Software Alternative, not tested**

Another software that is an alternative to Multipoint is [SoftXpand](http://www.miniframe.com/technology/softxpand.html) which I have never used or encountered before, so I can't vouch for it. It isn't free but it might be something you want to look at.

**Thin Clients**

Awhile back PC thin clients were a thing, and I have seen these underpowered half-pcs deployed in labs for educational use and as a kiosk. However it is fairly outdated and underpowered. Nevertheless it's an approach.

**Raspberry Pi(s)**

Lastly, since you're focused on having one PC act like '2 different devices', perhaps for the ease of setup it is better to have 2 physically different devices. Cheaper options are refurbished PCs, or even the cheap windows tablets that can connect to HDMI and output to a screen, or even an AIO. However the cheapest possible option that might actually be viable in the near future is the Raspberry Pi. I say near future because it has been confirmed that the [Raspberry Pi will be supported by Windows 10](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/featured/raspberrypi2support), and since they cost $40 for the CPU, all you need is the monitor, mouse, keyboard and a memory card. (You did not mention what existing peripherals you have so it's might or might not be considered as a cost for you)

**Maintaining 2 different devices**

As for maintaining the separate devices, VNC or TeamViewer should be able to do the job so the first user (assuming works for the company) can easily remotely troubleshoot the computer used by the customer or user as you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

softxpand really works. Even for gaming. You can get a trial for 30 days. i wish there was a free alternative to it currently. (my trial is about to go boom lol)

im currently using a core 2 quad 2.5 ghz, 8 gb ram, ati 270x (this card has 2 dvi and a hdmi) (i also use the intel g41 onboard)  - and if i had enough usb ports i could run 4 workstations from the trial. i run 2 atm.

best wishes coding - and i would really like to see your endeavour flourish.